# PRO / CONS of using app model vs web services

Tags: 2013, web-services, provider-hosted-app

I'm trying to tally up what are the PROs and CONs of using a provider hosted app model vs implementing the same application by speaking with SHP via the webservices like Lists.asmx and Copy.asmx.

Are there things that can't be done by working directly with those web services. I know that the app model is sold as being future-proof, are the WS deprecated?

I'm asking because I'm trying to push for the app model (since it should be the way forward), but my client is having trouble justifying the cost of configuring the SHP farm to work correctly with that model.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The key differentiation I see between the provider hosted app and standard in browser stuff, is the provider hosted model gets you a slew of other capabilities. You are spinning up a web application in Azure or locally where you can write your own custom APIs to integrate into your own systems or other routine timer job type functions.

Using the web layer with SharePoint won't get you the deeper integration or automation you might be looking for. So as always, it depends. Don't roll out "the path forward" if they don't need it and when they do, then do it.

Comment: +1, timer jobs and integration points are the big use cases for PHAs. I would add site provisioning to that mix as well.

Comment: @DerekGusoff true, site provisioning is another potential use case, ours stems from a separate help desk application that executes powershell to provision, but that is covered in the PnP repo I believe

Comment: thanks for the response, but to be clear I'm not talking about provider hosted vs sharepoint hosted. I'm talking about provider hosted, vs a web app that talks with SHP via the web services